# jQuery Zoom-in and Zoom-Out is not working

Tags: jquery, zooming

I am attempting to zoom-in and zoom-out out of a photo when a button is pressed, however I am unable to get the code to work properly I believe this is do to the way i have structured the zoom-out part of my code.

jQuery code:

```
      $(".enlarge-photo").click(function(){
    //photo - zoom-in
        var $img = $(".image");
    $img.stop().animate({ 
    height: "365", 
    width: "269", 
    paddingRight: "12"},"fast");

  },function(){
        $img.stop().animate({
        height: "265",
        width: "169",
        paddingRight: "0"},"fast");
  });
```

This is the HTML I am using:

```
<figure>
            <img class="image" src="img/basketball.jpg" width="169" height="265" border="0" alt="basketball dunk"/>
            <figcaption>Laura Skelding/AMERICAN-STATESMAN</figcaption>
        </figure>

            <ul id="photo">
                <li rel="nofollow"><a class="enlarge-photo" href="#" title="enlarge-photo">ENLARGE PHOTO</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: can you put the HTML code, are you sure that image is a class and not an id?

Comment: Your example javascript isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: Hi CAbbott, I'm still unable to format my code correctly can you show me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact you want a button to do it:

```
$("#zoom").button().click(function () {
    var options = { height: "365", width: "269", paddingRight: "12"};
    var myImage = $("#myImage");
    if (myImage.hasClass("zoomed"))
    {
        options = {height: "265", width: "169"};
    }

    myImage.stop().animate(options,"fast");
    myImage.toggleClass("zoomed");
});​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/NhYtL/19/

Comment: I believe the formatting of my jquery script is incorrect. When I remove the zoom-out portion of my code i am able to zoom-in properly but when i re-add the zoom-out the code does not work at all.

Comment: @user1584751 the issue is your `click` function, 
http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/NhYtL/5/ try changing the `click` or `hover` and it will works

Comment: Thank You all for your help. I am using an icon as my trigger with the class '.enlarge-photo' that will both enlarge and return to normal size an image with a class '.image'. When I place the trigger click or hover on the image directly the code works however this is not what i am attempting to do, I would like the icon ".enlarge-photo' to be the trigger 'click'.

Comment: Thank you John and everyone that helped. The zoom script is now working.