# Button Zoom In does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

http://via.placeholder.com/350x150

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="Zoom In" id="btnZoomIn"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
<a href="#" title="Zoom Out" id="btnZoomOut"><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i></a>
<div id="canvas">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>

<script>
  $("#btnZoomIn").on("click", function() {
    var cwidth = parseInt($("#canvas img").css("width"));
    var nwidth = cwidth * 1.3;
    $("#canvas img").css("width", nwidth + "px").css("height", "auto");
  });
  $("#btnZoomOut").on("click", function() {
    var cwidth = parseInt($("#canvas img").css("width"));
    var nwidth = cwidth / 1.3;
    $("#canvas img").css("width", nwidth + "px").css("height", "auto");
  });
</script>
```

The natural width & height of the image is 1324 x 2041 while the rendered dimension is 650 x 1002.

Button Zoom Out works perfectly as it reduces the size of the image as per code.However, button Zoom In does not work.It increases the size of the image the first time, thereafter it does not increase the size of the image.

Please advise what am i doing wrong with some codes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently, you're missing the "v" - *"verifiable"*; the code in your example does not replicate the issue you describe. [It seems to work perfectly.](https://jsfiddle.net/d7sLomb2/)

Comment: I think you can take reference from this fiddle shared in another question on stackoverflow. This guy is applying his function on hover, you can apply on click function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/NhYtL/5/)
and
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904962/jquery-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-is-not-working)